# python3 multiprocessing Manager constructor function dosnt return

Tags: python, multiprocessing

im tring to use the multiprocessing Manager but if i write this

```
import multiprocessing as mp
m = mp.Manager()
```

the code seams to block on line 2
but if I do the same thing in the schell so

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> m = mp.Manager()
```

then m is a manager

mp.Manager() cals line 48 of context.py in multiprocessing lib
witch defines this function

```
def Manager(self):
        '''Returns a manager associated with a running server process

        The managers methods such as `Lock()`, `Condition()` and `Queue()`
        can be used to create shared objects.
        '''
        from .managers import SyncManager
        m = SyncManager(ctx=self.get_context())
        m.start()
        return m
```

the execution apears to get stucke on m.start (ln 56)

there the blocking seams to hapen on ln 517 of manager.py in multiprocessing lib aka self._address = reader.recv() in this function

```
def start(self, initializer=None, initargs=()):
        '''
        Spawn a server process for this manager object
        '''
        assert self._state.value == State.INITIAL

        if initializer is not None and not callable(initializer):
            raise TypeError('initializer must be a callable')

        # pipe over which we will retrieve address of server
        reader, writer = connection.Pipe(duplex=False)

        # spawn process which runs a server
        self._process = self._ctx.Process(
            target=type(self)._run_server,
            args=(self._registry, self._address, self._authkey,
                  self._serializer, writer, initializer, initargs),
            )
        ident = ':'.join(str(i) for i in self._process._identity)
        self._process.name = type(self).__name__  + '-' + ident
        self._process.start()

        # get address of server
        writer.close()
        self._address = reader.recv()
        reader.close()

        # register a finalizer
        self._state.value = State.STARTED
        self.shutdown = util.Finalize(
            self, type(self)._finalize_manager,
            args=(self._process, self._address, self._authkey,
                  self._state, self._Client),
            exitpriority=0
            )
```

I belive that the process self._process = self._ctx.Process(...) [ln 506] never gets around to sending the required data to the writer but i dont know how to work around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the Manager is created a the file is executed which creates a new `Manager` and the loop repeats forever. When peforming the operations in the shell this dose not happen as there is no file to be executed. To solve the problem you have to put the `m = mp.Manager()` in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause or some other method of ensure the infinite loop i broken.